# Scale Magento on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have looked in the Magento & AWS Documentation but that didn't really help.

I've installed Magento on Elastic Beanstalk with 1 instance, I proceeded to snapshot the volume and make an AMI and changed the AMI setting in Elastic Beanstalk. Then spun up 2 more instances in the other availability zones. They went back to the Magento installation pages.

How do I fix this? I thought the AMI made from the snapshot would of captured the DB and other files created on installation. Meaning they'd just connect the DB and run.

Cheers to anyone who helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want your database installed on your EC2 inside the elastic beanstalk. Since elastic beanstalk just removes the instance when there is an error on it and spawns a new one. You then end up loosing data. Besides that you need 1 single database server, not a database server on each of the EC2 instances inside the elastic beanstalk.
You want a separate database server, I personally always use Amazon RDS for this since this is made for this purpose.

When you are getting the install page it probably means Magento cannot locate your app/etc/local.xml. Since AWS normally gets your files from git and it is best practice to not have your local.xml in version control you are probably missing this one?

Hope that I pointed you in the right direction.
Keep in mind that the database is just your first challange, next things you are going to need to handle is:

- Sessions (database is a good option but I use AWS ElastiCache with
  Redis)
- Cache (again, AWS ElastiCache with Redis)
- Media Storage (I use S3 with S3FS and CloudFront)
- CDN (CloudFront)

Here are some sites that have helped me setting up my first elastic beanstalks with Magento:

http://www.aschroder.com/2013/04/actually-running-magento-on-amazons-elastic-beanstalk-cloud-platform/

http://www.slideshare.net/corleycloud/scale-your-magento-app-with-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: Cheers mate!!! i'll have to look at copying the local.xml and adding it to other instances or even right in the application file so is there from launch. I already use RDS as that seemed the logical choice since multiple instances will be connecting up. Cheers for helping, i'll let you know how it plays out. :)